# Sonar (software quality) - extending sonar (controllers and views)

Tags: model-view-controller, plugins, sonarqube

I have been fiddling with SONAR for some time now, and I would like to extend it to some point. I don't think I will be able to achieve this with a custom plugin but if I would introduce an additional controller and some views - it would get the job done.

Now as I understand, MVC model in sonar is written in RUBY, and I have yet to do research on ruby coding, but before I get to that - is my goal reasonable/achievable ?

Or can additional views and controllers can be added via plugin extensions ?

Basically I just need certain information gathered from sonar DataBase about the project, and displayed in a custom view for additional statistics.

Thanks.

P.S. I have hard time finding information for sonar development, maybe someone could recommend some forums discussing sonar extension topics ?

Comment: you can always try the mailing list: http://www.sonarsource.org/support/support/

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible yet to add Ruby controllers and views at the same time through a Sonar plugin. Currently, when extending Sonar Web interface, you can only:

- Add a Ruby widget (that will be displayed on a dashboard): this is **only** a view
- Add a Ruby web service API: this is **only** a controller
- Add a GWT extension: here you can define a controller **and** a view

However, please note that we will drop GWT support in the future, and replace it with the possibility to define extension points that allow to write both controllers and views in Ruby.

So to answer your need, I would advise you to write a widget, like the ones you can see on Sonar source code here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar/tree/master/plugins/sonar-core-plugin/src/main/resources/org/sonar/plugins/core/widgets

HTH